# Event Report with amount paid and balance owing by participant

Tags: civireport, payment, civicrm-event

CiviCRM 5.55.0  Wordpress

Trying to pull a report (export output preferred) to provide a list of registered participants that includes the total amount owing, total paid, and fee level. I have reviewed several posts on various forums indicating a "balance" owing is available as a selected field for export; however, unable to locate the field in custom reports.  The report is intended to be used at check-in and would ideally primarily based on the event, list the participants with the event fee level, total paid, and balance owing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the core Attendee List report may meet your needs - you can add additional columns for example for fee level, amount paid and balance on the 'Columns' tab and filter by event on the filter tab.

Unfortunately you would have to change the filter as necessary each time you run the report so there may be a Search Kit option that has more defaults sets and exposes the filter for easier searching and exporting.